# How do I display products with JOIN in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, filter, size, e-commerce

I am trying to figure out how to display a product with the sizes that it has. Now it is displayed with duplication.

[image: My product table]

[image: My product specification table]

**'Maat' being sizes and 'Voorraad' being stock**

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producten JOIN product_specificaties";
```

Comment: You can read the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html . You need a "join specification", with `ON` clause

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
  FROM producten p
  JOIN product_specificaties s
    ON p.id = s.product_id
";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the products display without duplicate, but it displays like this: Barakah Shirt (S), Barakah Shirt (M). How can I prevent it from showing the same product but with different size?

Comment: well you can just print it together with the naam and maat like this


echo $row["naam"]."(".$row["maat"].")";

Answer (score 0):

Returns general information, you can use select or other items, say if you have something specific

```
SELECT * FROM producten INNER JOIN product_specificaties ON
producten.id=product_specificaties.product_id;
```